# POST Form Submission in JQuery/AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I'm a bit new to working with form submissions in JQuery/AJAX and PHP, so I've been trying to follow some tutorials online and have run into a few issues.

I am trying to build a form that handles submissions through PHP. Here's what I have for my index.html file.

```
<body>

    <h1>Food Preference</h1>

    <p>Please let us know what types of foods you would like to see on the menu.</p>

    <form id="food-form">
        <label for="appetizer">Appetizer</label>
        <input type="text" id="appetizer" required>

        <label for="entree">Entree</label>
        <input name="entree" type="entree" id="entree" required>

        <label for="dessert">Dessert</label>
        <textarea name="dessert" id="dessert" required></textarea>

        <button id="submit_button" type="submit">Send</button>

        <p id="form_content">
        </p>
    </form>
```

And here is my index.js file

```
 jQuery.ajax({
        url: "handler.php",
        data: "appetizer=" + $("#appetizer").val() +
              "&entree=" + $("#entree").val() +
              "&dessert=" + $("#dessert").val(),
              type: "POST",
              success: function(data) {
                  $("#form_content").html(data);
              },
              error: function() {}
    });
```

And here is handler.php

```
<?php

class runForm {
public function handle_food_form($request) {

    if(opinion($_POST["appetizer"], $_POST["entree"], $_POST["dessert"])) {
        print "<p class='success'>Thank you for your opinion.</p>";

        return array('post_id' => $new_post_id );
    }
 }
}

runForm();
?>
```

It doesn't seem like my submission saves anywhere, or if it does, I'm not sure how to find it. Can anyone give any pointers for anything I might be doing wrong?

I am wondering if this line in handler.php is correct, since I haven't really defined "opinion".

```
if(opinion($_POST["appetizer"], $_POST["entree"], $_POST["dessert"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Separate the variables with commas.
In jQuery.ajax, do as like:

```
 jQuery.ajax({
        url: "handler.php",
        data: "appetizer=" + $("#appetizer").val(),
              "entree=" + $("#entree").val(),
              "dessert=" + $("#dessert").val(),
              type: "POST",
              success: function(data) {
                  $("#form_content").html(data);
              },
              error: function() {}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many issues in this code snippet, and you should first check the errors that PHP shows to you and try to resolve them first.

#### The PHP file (handler.php)

1. `opinion()` function is not defined.
2. `runForm()` is not a function , it's a name of a class, if you want to call `handle_food_form()` function, then you can make it a static function and call it like this `runForm::handle_food_form();`
3. The final version of your PHP file should be something like this

   ```
   <?php


   class RunForm {

       public static function opinion($appetizer, $entree, $dessert)
       {
           // do your logic here and return true or false
           return true;
       }

       public static function handle_food_form() {

           if (!isset($_POST["appetizer"])) $_POST["appetizer"] = null;
           if (!isset($_POST["appeentreetizer"])) $_POST["entree"] = null;
           if (!isset($_POST["dessert"])) $_POST["dessert"] = null;

           if(SELF::opinion($_POST["appetizer"], $_POST["entree"], $_POST["dessert"])) {
               $htmlMsg =  "<p class='success'>Thank you for your opinion.</p>";
               /*
                   $con is a MySQLI object
                   $con->query("insert into table ........");
                   $new_post_id = $con->insert_id;
               */

               return array('post_id' => $new_post_id, 'htmlMsg' => $htmlMsg );
           } else {
               return array('post_id' => null , 'htmlMsg' => "");
           }
       }
   }

   echo RunForm::handle_food_form()['htmlMsg'];
   ```

#### The client side

You should use [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to encode the paramters of the URL to prevent something like this `dessert=cheesecake&pancake` from corrupting the URL, or pass an object of the parameters as the data to `ajax` function and jquery will do the encoding for you internally

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "handler.php",
    data: {
              appetizer: $("#appetizer").val(),
              entree: $("#entree").val(),
              dessert: $("#dessert").val()
           },
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
              $("#form_content").html(data);
          },
      error: function() {}
});
```